# three "groups of musicians"

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

### What should replace the question mark? Explain why.

---

**If,**

```
   001 111 100
  |   |   |   |
  |   |   |   | = 2:3
  |   |   |   |


   010 111 100
  |   |   |   |
  |   |   |   | = 2:3
  |   |   |   |


   100 111 100
  |   |   |   |
  |   |   |   | = 2:3
  |   |   |   |
```

**Then,**

```
   000 110 100
  |   |   |   |
  |   |   |   | = ?
  |   |   |   |
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question mark should be replaced by:

> **13:15**

Because a 'group of musicians' is a:

> **band**, and so *three* groups of musicians are a **[triband](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triband_(flag))**, a word which is used in vexillology to mean *a flag with three coloured stripes*.

Now we realise that these line images must represent...

> ...**triband flags**, with their two key properties encoded:
>
>  1. The three colours are represented by the three binary triplets. The three 0/1 columns of each triplet represent the **RGB** [colour model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) - column 1 represents red, column 2 is green, and column 3 is blue, with a '1' in a column indicating the presence of that colour, and a '0' its absence.
>
>  2. The ratio of the lengths of the two dimensions of the flag, height:width.

The three examples can be interpreted as...

> the flags of **France**, **Italy** and **Peru**:
>
>  001 | 111 | 100 is blue, white, red (since 111, the presence of red, green and blue all together makes white) - the colours of the flag of France
>
>  010 | 111 | 100 is green, white, red - the colours of the flag of Italy
>
>  100 | 111 | 100 is red, white, red - the colours of the flag of Peru
>
>  [image: Flags of France, Italy and Peru]

So the final combination makes...

> the flag of **Belgium**:
>
>  000 | 110 | 100 is black, yellow, red (since 000 - the absence of red, green and blue - makes black, and 110 - the presence of red and green together - makes yellow.
>
>  [image: Flag of Belgium]
>
>  And the [relative dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_aspect_ratios_of_national_flags) of the sides of the Belgian flag are **13:15**, which is the answer we seek.

Comment: Ahh, that's clever

Comment: Correct. Well done!